# Return value if scores contain value form min and Max column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Formula to [image]

I want to write a formula in b4 to get the grade if my score in column Ais in between min marks column d and Max marks column E. Please refer to attached pic for clarity.

Comment: It looks like a home assignment. Perhaps you could try. `=INDEX(F$4:F$13,MATCH(1,(A4>=D$4:D$13)*(A4<=E$4:E$13),0))` or with `XLOOKUP()` --> `=XLOOKUP(1,(A4>=D$4:D$13)*(A4<=E$4:E$13),$F$4:$F$13,"")` also I like using defined names within formulas hence define the top rows of each column in right table and can use `=XLOOKUP(1,(A4>=Min_Marks)*(A4<=Max_Marks),Grade,"")`

Comment: Thanks for your response but I m not getting result it's giving some error can you help

Comment: That may be because, based on Excel Version you need to hit `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` while exiting the edit mode. Do you want me to post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on my comments above, here are the screenshots where the formula is working. Since I am using `MS365` therefore I don't need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when exiting edit mode for the second alternative, but for those using earlier versions needs to hit.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A4>=Min_Marks)*(A4<=Max_Marks),Grade,"")
```

---

Where: Min_Marks, Max_Marks & Grade are defined names for the ranges, --> `=$D$4:$D$13`, `=$E$4:$E$13`, `=$F$4:$F$13` you can also use without using defined names.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A4>=D$4:D$13)*(A4<=E$4:E$13),$F$4:$F$13,"")
```

---

Alternatively if you don't have access to `XLOOKUP()` then use `INDEX()` with `MATCH()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=INDEX(Grade,MATCH(1,(A4>=Min_Marks)*(A4<=Max_Marks),0))
```

---

Or, without defined names:

```
=INDEX(F$4:F$13,MATCH(1,(A4>=D$4:D$13)*(A4<=E$4:E$13),0))
```

---

Note: Remember to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode for the second formula.